# Is it a good idea to evaluate cross-validation using correlation coefficient?

Tags: cross-validation

I am doing cross-validation of my model. I was looking for a metric, that would be able to compare the predictions with the independent data, and I thought that correlation coefficient *r* would be very easy to interpret. So, just correlate the predictions with the data. But I am not a statistician, so I might have overlooked some issues. So, is it actually a good idea to do this?

P.S.: in my particular model the data are counts or sometimes averaged counts, so numbers >= 0, poisson-like distributed, so maybe some normalization would be needed.... but let's keep the question more general :-)

Answer (score 1):

The correlation coefficient isn't really a measure of predictive performance (except in the special case of linear regression). For example, these two vectors have 100% correlation:

```
y <- 1:100
yhat <- 50 + (1:100)/2
cor(y, yhat)  # 1
```

That said, it's a measure that most people will recognise, and unless your models are going very wrong, a higher correlation generally means more accurate predictions.

Other measures you can use include:

- Mean squared error:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum(y - \hat{y})^2$$

- Mean absolute error:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum|y-\hat{y}|$$

- Mean absolute percentage error:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum \frac{|y - \hat{y}|}{y}$$

The last one probably makes the most sense for strictly positive data, but be aware that if the denominator is small, you can get an exaggerated error measure.

Comment: Hi Hong Ooi, I didn't understand your example. The correlation of the two vectors is -1, so the predictions are terrible. I would consider model as good when r is between 0.5 and 1.

Comment: Ok, modified it; it doesn't really change my point. The _squared_ correlation ($R^2$) is what I was thinking of.

Comment: Ok, I see now! But in my particular case, different intercept and slope is not a problem (it would be hard to explain [why](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141005/5509)). So is there any other problem of the correlation coefficient besides the illustrated one with intercept and slope? If not, I consider it perfect measure for my case!!